# numpy solve for eigenvector using eigenvalue but all gives zero as result

Tags: numpy, matrix, eigenvector

I want to verify that v will give me the same result if I follow the equation
(A - IL)x = 0, however the result are all zeros. Any idea why this would happen? Is there something wrong with my equation implementation?

```
def all_eigenvectors(Z, L):
    eigenvector = []
    for eigenvalue in L:
        eigenvector.append(np.linalg.solve(Z - eigenvalue * np.identity(20), [[0] for _ in range(20)]))
        
    return eigenvector

print(all_eigenvectors(Z, L))

w, v = np.linalg.eig(Z)
```

Comment: *"... the result are all zeros. Any idea why this would happen?"*  Because that is a correct answer.  To get the eigenvector, you want a *nonzero solution*, but `solve` doesn't "know" that.

Comment: Is there a way to tell the solve function to ignore the trivial solution?